# Redirect to Checkout Page on press of continue buy

Tags: php, url-rewriting, checkout

How I apply a condition in my login page so if user click's continue to checkout button and goes on login page and once he logged in so he don't go on home page but he goes in checkout page.

I have tried query string method where I added checkout string after login URL like this `login.php/checkout` so I easily get that string and compare with my string like "checkout" if true then checkout.php else home.php.

but this also not worked.

My Code:

```
if(strlen($_SESSION['login'])==0) {
    header('location:login.php?page=checkout');
}

if($_GET['page']=="checkout") {
    header('location:checkout.php');
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: if(strlen($_SESSION['login'])==0)
    {   
header('location:login.php?page=checkout');
}

if($_GET['page']=="checkout")
   {
    header('location:checkout.php');
   }

Comment: You can pass a GET parameter, e.g. if the customer comes from the cart the url will be something like `myurl.com/login.php?redirect=checkout`.

Comment: you better should test first if `$_SESSION['login']` is set and then check for the value.

Comment: i have checked it and its not working in login page

Comment: Please post some of the code for the login page, this may help to find the problem.

Comment: `login.php/checkout` this will only work if you have done some url-rewriting or some other methods.

Comment: url is like this if user click continue to checkout then on login page url 
will be login.php?page=checkout

Comment: `login.php?page=checkout` should work just fine. simply use `$page = $_GET['page'] ? $_GET['page'] : null;` Then you can check wether `$page` is null to determine if you have to redirect after login.